# How do i initialize int[][]?

Tags: c#, arrays

In C# how do i initialize

```
int[][] test;
```

I don't want to use `int[,]` instead. I am asking specifically how to initialize the above. The obvious `= int[1][1]` does not work. I tried a few different ways with no luck and [][] is not really google-able unfortunately (unless its possible!?)

Comment: 'not really googleable'? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx first result :)

Comment: maybe he didn't know what to call it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's called *jagged arrays* if you want to Google it.

Basically you can initialize the first dimension in the traditional way :

```
int[][] test = new int[23][];
```

And you manually initialize the others :

```
for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; ++i)
    test[i] = new int[42];
```

Answer (score 5):

You need a for-loop to initialize an *array of array*.

```
int[][] test = new int[N][];

for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i ++)
   test[i] = new int [M];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int[][] scores = new int[5][];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is called a [Jagged Array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2s05feca.aspx). So basically you have initialize the "first dimension" first and then each element:

```
int[][] foo = new int[3][];

foo[0] = new int[2];
...
```